# Include two Commerce Add to Cart forms on one page

Tags: 8, forms

With two forms on one page, I'm experiencing the error `Error: Call to a member function id() on null in Drupal\commerce_product\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ProductVariationTitleWidget->formElement()`

This is happening on two different types of pages, but both involve Commerce add to cart forms.

I have two different types of pages:

1. Commerce Product.  This has an optional Commerce Product entity reference field.
2. Landing page. This page is built using paragraphs and site builders have a paragraph which is a block containing an add to cart form for a product they select

On the Commerce Product page, clicking Add To Cart for the entity reference item results in the error.  On the Landing Page, clicking *any* of the Add to Cart buttons produces the error.

So far, I'm debugging the Commerce Product page.

`AddToCartFormatter:viewElements` is always getting the main entity of the page.

`ProductLazyBuilders::addToCartForm` receives a product_id as it's first argument.  The product ID comes from the entity and I've been tracing it up the stack to `HTMLRenderer::prepare` in which `$main_content` is the entity being viewed - this would explain why none of the Landing Page add to cart forms work and why only the Add To Cart form for the main entity on the Commerce Product page works.

EDIT: It might be important to note that all forms are built correctly.  If I watch `ProductLazyBuilders::addToCartForm()` it gets correct product id's and all the forms are correct insofar as they show the right variations.

EDIT 2: The entity is set in `ContentEntityForm::form()` using `$this->entity` which, apparently, is the entity being viewed.

EDIT 3: If I wanted to hack together a solution, it works to do something like this:
In `Drupal\commerce_cart\Form\AddToCartForm::buildForm()` I can add:

```
$form_state->addBuildInfo('entity', $this->entity);
```

And then, within `Drupal\Core\Entity\Content\ContentEntityForm::form()` add

```
if ($form_state->getBuildInfo()['entity']) {
  $this->entity = $form_state->getBuildInfo()['entity'];
}
```

This makes the Landing Page *"work"*.

EDIT 4: #3 doesn't fix anything except the first product on the page, so now there is one that works.

So, I guess I have a couple questions:

1. At what point does a form decide which form is being submitted?
2. Am I missing something obvious that would allow for this setup to work?

Comment: Argh! The fix is https://www.drupal.org/node/2897698

Comment: Consider writing a brief answer instead of a comment so that the question can be marked solved.